# react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: react-native, axios, node-modules

I am new to react native, I was learning the Axios, for that I tried to install it by using command

```
npm install axios
```

but later on, my app started showing this error

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native from D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\index.js: react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:


node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  3 |  */
  4 |
> 5 | import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    |                            ^
  6 | import App from './App';
  7 | import {name as appName} from './app.json';
  8 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:129:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async traverseDependencies (D:\work\app_dev\AxiosWorking\AxiosProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:60:7)
```

[image: codebase]

Comment: can you share your package.json file? it will help better in understanding the actual problem.